# Release VideoWriter in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Does anybody know what the command to release a VideoWriter object in python is?

In my code I import the following:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
```

The documentation I can find does not say how to release the videoObject using cv2 or python at all. That is the documentation for OpenCV 2.4.5.0.

I've tried

```
cv.ReleaseVideoWriter(videoWriter)
```

and other random combinations using cv2 and cv. Nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: May be it is released automatically when you exit the program.

Answer (score 5):

I compiled OpenCV 2.4.5 from its source in Fedora, and it does have a release function. Please see my IPython session which demonstrates this feature.

```
In [22]: out = cv2.VideoWriter('out.avi', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'MJPG'), 30.0, (100, 100), False)

In [23]: out.isOpened()
Out[23]: True

In [24]: out.    # Press `Tab`, Just checking available methods, see release is there
out.avi       out.isOpened  out.open      out.release   out.write     

In [24]: out.release()

In [25]: out.isOpened()
Out[25]: False
```

So please check your version.

Comment: When I type "out." and then press the Tab key, out.release isn't an available method.

Comment: which version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
videoWriter = None
```

Source: "OpenCV Computer Vision with Python, by Joseph Howse", chapter 2.

Comment: This is works like a charm, must be the accepted answer.