# AttributeError: 'cv2.VideoWriter' object has no attribute 'release'

Tags: python, linux, opencv, video

```
   import cv2
   camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   video  = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', -1, 25, (640, 480));
   while True:
      f,img = camera.read()
      video.write(img)
      cv2.imshow("webcam",img)
      if (cv2.waitKey(5) != -1):
           break
   video.release()
```

I am trying to play a video and save it in a file video.avi but I have this error and I can find many people asking about this problem but no one answers

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: opencv version ? (cv2.getBuildInformation()) - above code seems to run fine with 2.4.9

Comment: If your building in release mode User... you got to make sure you are using the release binaries and not the debug ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Release VideoWriter in Python OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076091/release-videowriter-in-python-opencv)